# Problems updating the Repository

Tags: typo3

I have problems updating the repository.
After a fresh installation of Typo3 I clicked on "Extension Manager -> Import Extensions -> Retrieve/Update". After 30 seconds I received an exception, that the max. execution time has exceeded, only 347 extensiones have been added, at the bottom it says "Page 1 of 31", but the actual field, where all the extensions are supposed to be, remains empty.
When I set the max execution time on 90 and try it again, I receive the same exception and the number of the extensions doesn't change.
Even if I search for an extension, it only says "Searching" without any results.

I'm using the newest version of Typo3 (4.7.1) on my local server (XAMPP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use an different TER-Mirror. Change it in the settings-tab of the extension manager.

Check your table cache_extensions where the information is stored. Check which extensions are added. Check in your install tool -> "Basic configuration" if you have trouble with some temorary folders? Check your memory settings - just raise them. And check your php error log for some hints.

If you have another working TYPO3 installation, you could just import the table cache_extensions from there. Should work (but never did on my own).

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem on a fresh Debian server with "Import Extensions", missing "php5-curl" package.

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

Hope it helps somebody.